# Can't open project solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I changed computers. Backed up my projects folder to the server, changed computers, installed VS, moved the projects folder back to the C: drive. Now, I can't open my projects. They say they're "unloaded". All the data is there. How do I open these projects?

Comment: What happens when you right-click the unloaded project and choose `Reload Project`? Also, are you sure it say's "unloaded" and not "UnAvailable" ?

Comment: Have you tried Right clicking on the project and click reload project?

Comment: It appears it has to do with package security. I found comments elsewhere that suggest if I change the package security (right click in the package background (??) and select properties, then change to NOT save personal information, it may work.) I'm testing now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when i downloaded the project sent via email.
The downloaded files were "blocked" by the Windows 7 OS. I had to `right click->properties->unblock` every file.
Post this, the project was successfully loaded.

Answer (score -1):

You should delete the *.suo file.